# How to get the data from following XMl?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application in which I am getting XML as below. How to parse the following XML such that I need to maintain two separate arrays for 'id' and 'last updated'. In idArray I want to maintain all the ids and in updatedArrays I want to maintain all the dates.How to do that? Both id and lastUpdate are within a single tag as below.

id="amitdixit007@gmail.com"  lastUpdate="08/27/2010 04:15:42PM"

Answer (score 0):

can u tell me the link or response string so i can help you;

hold the response after parse in array and then do in like this
nsmutablearray *idarray = [[nsmutablearray alloc]init];
nsmutablearray *lastUpdatearray = [[nsmutablearray alloc]init];
(for i=0;i<[array count];i++){

[idarray addobject:[[ array objectatindex:i]valueforkey:@"id"]];
[lastUpdatearray addobject:[[ array objectatindex:i]valueforkey:@"lastUpdate"]]
}

Comment: resopnse from web service is already given above as <user>id=amitdixit007@gmail.com lastUpdate="08/27/2010 04:15:42PM"</user> As data coming from web service hw can u access elements using valueforkey:@"id"? When you parse the tag you will get {id=amitdixit007@gmail.com    lastUpdate="08/27/2010 04:15:42PM"} as a single element.And I want maintain two separate arrays for id and lastUpdate.

Comment: resopnse from already givel above as               <user>id=amitdixit007@gmail.com    lastUpdate="08/27/2010 04:15:42PM"</user> As data coming from web service hw can u access elements using valueforkey:@"id"? When you parse the tag you will get {id=amitdixit007@gmail.com    lastUpdate="08/27/2010 04:15:42PM"} as a single elememt.And I want maintain two separate arrays for id and lastUpdate.

Comment: yes u got dictionary on every index of array and above code is used for access and make two diffrent array